# Unable to install git on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: apt, software-installation, 15.10, git

I tried installing git by `sudo apt-get install git`. But I got error.

```
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package git is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source                                                          
E: Package 'git' has no installation candidate
```

I also tried `sudo apt-get install git-core` and got this error

```
E: Unable to locate package git-core
```

since my current stack overflow reputation does not allow to post more than 2 link here.
So, here is [pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/5VJu16gz) for the output of `grep '^[^#]' /etc/apt/sources.list`.

After doing `sudo apt-get update' I got error:

> Failed to fetch. Network is unreachable.

Here is [complete output](http://pastebin.com/2pucHaiM).

**Edit:**
Output of `sudo apt-get install git`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package git is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
E: Package 'git' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: [edit] your question and add the output of `grep '^[^#]' /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: Do `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install git`

Answer (score 1):

First check if you can ping the gateway whatever it is in your case like

ping 192.168.0.1(your gateway in here)

if you revice and reply check if the route is corrent
temporarily disable network-manager

```
sudo service network-manager stop

sudo ifconfig eth0(your adapter) 192.168.0.12/24(your ip) up
sudo route add default gw 192.168.0.1(your gateway)
sudo -i
echo "nameserver 208.67.222.222" > /etc/resolv.conf (opendns dont change these two)
echo "nameserver 208.67.220.220" >> /etc/resolv.conf
```

**check route**

```
route
```

then do

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install git
```

if all works then change the settings in network-manager accordingly
and if 
`sudo apt-get update` works but

`sudo apt-get install git`

dosent works
then do it manually bu these steps

1) Install dpendencies

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev libexpat1-dev gettext unzip
```

o ahead and get the version of git you want by visiting the git project's page on [GitHub](https://github.com/git/git).

*The version you see* when you arrive at the project's page is the branch that is actively being committed to. If you want the latest stable release, you should go change the branch to the latest **non-"rc" tag**

2) Next, on the right side of the page, right-click the **Download ZIP**
button and select the option similar to "Copy Link Address"

3)

```
wget https://github.com/git/git/archive/v1.9.2.zip -O git.zip
```

your version will vary

4)

```
unzip git.zip
cd git-*

make prefix=/usr/local all
sudo make prefix=/usr/local install
```

4) Now that you have git installed, if you want to upgrade to a later version, you can simply clone the repository and then build and install

```
git clone https://github.com/git/git.git
```

To find the URL to use for the clone operation, navigate to the branch or tag that you want on the project's [GitHub](https://github.com/git/git) page and then copy the clone URL on the right side

*This will create a new directory within your current directory where you can rebuild the package and reinstall the newer version, just like you did above. This will overwrite your older version*

5)

```
make prefix=/usr/local all
sudo make prefix=/usr/local install
```

Comment: FYI, I have also installed Ubuntu 14.04 in VMware player (Ubuntu 15.10 is installed in VMware Player) and everything is working fine there in Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: default route is default gateway?

Output of `sudo route add default gw 192.168.0.1(your gateway)` is 
>SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable

Comment: yes default route is default gateway change ip netmask and gateway to your needs but first stop network-manager temporarily then execute those commands with your ip netmask and gateway,and then if everything works restart the machine and apply those settings to network manager